# VBA Selecting a cell based of multiple critera

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to find a way to reference a cell in VBA based on two other cells in the datasheet.

In the datasheet I have a domain (D) column e.g. "example.com" and  I have a date column (A) e.g. 01/01/2017

In my main worksheet I have a table with domains in column A and the dates in row 10. I am trying to find a to pick the cell in the table that falls into the date and domain based on the record it is currently looking at in the datasheet

[Using that first line of data here is the an image highlighting the cell which I want to select](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6BStr.jpg).

My plan is to then copy the detail from the [Pass] column into that cell, I am just having problem selecting that cell.

I've tried as many solutions as I can find on here, most using one set of criteria, but I cannot seem to get them to work for me in this situation.

Many thanks

[Dummy data](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B14N9hS9gpltakNaMnB6QTM2YVU)

edit - added dummy data - had to remove screenshot of the data as I can only upload two links

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `Sheet2` is as follows

[image]

Then, in `Sheet1` enter the following formula in `Cell E2`

```
=INDEX(Sheet2!$A$10:$AH$17,MATCH(D2,Sheet2!$A$10:$A$17,0),MATCH(A2,Sheet2!$A$10:$AH$10,0))
```

Drag/Copy down as required. Change range as needed. See image for reference.

[image]

***EDIT :*** As per comment

---

Enter this formula in `Cell Z14`

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!$C$2:$C$5,MATCH(A14,Sheet1!$D$2:$D$5,0))
```

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. I have been trying it for the last hour but you have slightly misunderstood or I have poorly explained. It is sort of the reverse. 

In your sheet one I will already have the information I need. which is in the PASS column. I want to then go to  Sheet2 and then locate the cell that is between the data and domain of the record in Sheet1 and have it read the "PASS" column. So using your screenshots, how could I get cell Z14 to read IC from Sheet1?

Comment: Thank you @Mrig - I see I was trying to overcomplicate it with a script but this solution works perfectly.

Comment: @JoshMirkyMirkovic -  If above solution solved your problem kindly accept it as answer by clicking tick mark at top left of answer.